# Packet Filtering and Forwarding

Tags: filtering, packet, iptables, portforwarding

Can we filter all the packets coming to Host1:Port_A from *:Port_B and forward them to say Host1:Port_C.

I want to forward all the packets coming from port 9875 of any host at port 22 of my machine to port 5432 of my machine. What should be iptable rules corresponding to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --source-port 9876 --destination-port 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:5432
```

Don't forget to change address in destination :)